# React.js localStorage not causing correct re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement a simple "remember me" option for a login system in a React app. According to the console, it seems like everything should be working correctly. However, the rendered output continues to show the login screen. Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Login from '../Login/Login';
import GroupList from '../GroupList/GroupList';

// Flag to avoid infinite loop
let checkedLogin = false;
function App(props) {

  // State hooks
  const [isLoggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [userID, setUserID] = useState(null);

  // Load from session storage
  if("userID" in localStorage && !checkedLogin) {
    let newUserID = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("userID"));
    checkedLogin = true;
    loginComplete(newUserID);
  }

  // Callback function for login to update main app
  function loginComplete(newUserID) {

    // Set state variables
    setLoggedIn(true);
    setUserID(newUserID);

    // Save to localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('userID', JSON.stringify(newUserID));
  }


  console.log(userID);
  console.log(isLoggedIn);

  // JSX return
  if(isLoggedIn) {
    return <GroupList 
      API_ROUTE={props.API_ROUTE} 
      userID={userID}
      />

  }else{
    return <Login 
      API_ROUTE={props.API_ROUTE} 
      loginCallback={loginComplete}
      />
  }
}

export default App;
```

And here is what the console is returning:

[image]

If anyone has any advice, it is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping inside `useEffect`. and no need to create another variable checkedLogin you can use `isLoggedIn` only.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // Load from session storage
    if ("userID" in localStorage && !checkedLogin) {
      let newUserID = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("userID"));
      checkedLogin = true;
      loginComplete(newUserID);
    }
  }, [newUserID]);
```